# How to create only two edges rounded textView in android.?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I need to create a textview with only 
TopLeft and TopRight coners with round shape and no others,
I've written an XML for 4 corner round, but it not supporting for two corner round.
Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

any suggestions or help..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code provided, your are just one step from achieving what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

You can either comment out `android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"` and `android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"`, and add `android:radius="0dp"`, or set them to 0dp. So a result might be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: jyoon, i've tried it but not showing the preview, i''ll check for debuging also and have a comment on this.

Comment: This is just a bug with the IDE. The preview rendering is terrible. Also, accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: yeah, i'hv used it.....thanks for this help, i'll make ups when get my reputation lavel, still low

Comment: @ChathuraJayanath no, you need to click on the checkmark on the left side!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following `xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/grey" />
            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </selector>
```